# Mopub mediation admob stuck at welcome to mopub

Tags: admob, mopub, cocoonjs

I'm following this guide here to put some ads in my apps
https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/781/how-to-setup-admob-ads-on-construct-2-mopub-cocoonjs

Im using construct2 to build my apps, and right now my app is only showing welcome to mopub banner it's already 5 days i didnt get any ads.

On my mopub dashboard i got request but no impression and my ECPM is 0$ since what my apps showing is welcome to mopub I think ,also i already add admob to my mopub network and on my admob account it says that my apps is inactive because my apps didn't make any request to admob, and i dont why

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of items that can be explored to see what the issue may be.  A common issue is the AdMob credentials as you should be using your AdMob's 'Ad Unit ID' and not the 'Legacy Publisher ID.' I know it may be confusing as within MoPub's dashboard it mentions to have the 'Publisher ID' but really it should be the 'Ad Unit ID' from AdMob that should be entered.

Please consult this guide for more info: http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/1376821-how-to-set-up-updated-admob-revenue-reporting

The AdMob network needs to be turned on (activated) with a green icon once you input values in the eCPM field.  Have a value greater than $0.

Are you able to see ad creatives come in via the 'Test Ad' button in the MoPub UI dashboard?
That would dilute the issue down to Ad Unit ID setup prior to implementing it into your app.